# RobotFramework Directory Structure For Organizing Multiple Projects

Tags: robotframework, pageobjects

I am looking for some help defining my directory structure for automation tests using RobotFramework. I will be covering many apps within the same automation repo, for example:

- WebApp1
- WebApp2
- WebApp3
- REST-API
- AngularApp1
- AngularApp2
- iPhoneApp
- AndroidApp

There are some things that are common to all (eg sql connections etc). I have library's too. I want to have a separation of concerns (similar to the PageObjects pattern) by keeping resources/keywords separate from my test suites but I'm not sure how it should be organized. Can someone suggest a directory structure that would be typical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create Test suite for every Application
2. Within Test suite create 3 sub folders

   **resources** - files containing only keywords specific to application

   **templates** - xml files containing locators

   **testData** -  files containing data
3. **lib**  - contains all required libraries
4. **build.properties** - This file contains all server, database configuration  which can be used globally
5. **build.xml** - to build, clean, compile and execute testsuite.
6. Use **Ant** to execute test cases.